# Should I uninstall the softwares which Ubuntu has already in it?

Tags: system-installation

I am a lover of open source and I really want to install Ubuntu. But I afraid of something:

when I was looking for the features of Ubuntu I saw that Ubuntu is including some programs like Mozilla and Libreoffice. But I already installed these programs to my windows XP OS. So, İf I install Ubuntu, then, will these programs re-install themselves? Should I uninstall these programs before installing Ubuntu?

Thanks Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arhimed has pointed out, the softwares running on Windows will not run on Ubuntu even if they are the same softwares (like Mozilla and LibreOffice). When you install Ubuntu, Mozilla and LibreOffice will be installed for Ubuntu (not reinstalled because the programs running on Windows and Ubuntu function independently). You should not uninstall the programs in Windows if you intend to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, because installing them in Ubuntu means they will work only in Ubuntu and not in Windows.

Comment: Well, using Wine allow to run some Windows software, but you should do that only if there is no alternatives cause  performance of those apps will be less and also probably you'll get some bugs.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your answers Dineshkumar, Arhimed and user138156, I just started to install Ubuntu, and but I can't exit from this website, it is awesome to read features and design and other features of Ubuntu :D ! I really don't know why I was living as a slave of microsoft... :( 
thanks again for the answers :) .

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add about wine. Thanks for pointing it out @Arhimed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't.

Mozilla and LibreOffice on your Windows XP where compiled for Windows to run on Windows. Applications on Linux(also Ubuntu) where compiled to run on this OS.

Comment: Aha, of course, so, when I start Mozilla on Windows, the mozilla which complied for Windows will open, and when I start Mozilla on Ubuntu, the mozilla which compiled for Ubuntu will start, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're installing ubuntu as a dual boot win/linux system.

The windows versions of those programs are different binary executables than the linux versions.  So no, you don't need to uninstall the windows versions and they won't auto install in linux.  Though they may be installed as part of the linux install.

When I first installed ubuntu I actually used many of the same apps because I used mostly programs that were linux ports.  Linux programs tend to be better behaved.  They won't install 3rd party codec packs or otherwise screw up the windows registry.  Which is not much of a problem in linux.

Which ubuntu version are you thinking of installing?  If it's an older XP computer I'd recommend avoiding ubuntu with the unity desktop.  I had it on a 4Gb i3 laptop and I yanked it because it was too slow.  If your computer has 1Gb or more I'd try kubuntu or xubuntu.  Less than 1Gb, xubuntu or lubuntu.  512Mb or less, definitely lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Software installed on Ubuntu will only be accessible when logged into Ubuntu, just as software installed in Windows XP will only be available when you boot into windows XP. They are separate operating systems, with their own software installations.

A simple way to think of dual booting is that each operating system is like a box, each box is filled with it's own stuff, though often stored in the same room.

If you want to remove software from Ubuntu because you don't need it in both operating systems you can safely do so using the Ubuntu software center, or using apt-get, provided the software isn't part of the desktop environment package, both Mozilla Firefox and LibreOffice are not part of the desktop environment package, you can safely remove them.

In order to remove an application, open the Ubuntu Software Center, search for the application, click **Remove** and authenticate with your password to remove it... OR
...Open the terminal and type: `sudo apt-get remove package-name`.